# Кросскомпиляция в Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, кросс-компиляция

Необходимо собрать проект под систему на **32bit arm** из системы **x86_64** (надеюсь, в определениях не напутал, на интеловский x64 процессор, на целевой системе Cortex A7).

Проект включает в себя один лишь файл ***main.cpp***, и все бы ничего, если бы к нему помимо этого не была подключена статическая библиотека. Если бы не она, то можно было бы, скажем, собрать все на целевой системе, или собрать на десктопе, используя кросс-компилятор, но здесь же я не знаю как действовать без IDE. Раз так, необходимо создать комплект для Qt, который будет собирать сборку для моей целевой системы.

Установил:

- *g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf*
- *gcc-4.8-multilib g++-4.8-multilib*,
- *gcc-multilib g++-multilib*.

В Qt добавил компиляторы "arm" и "arm++", указав в них пути к исполняемым файлам *"/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"* и *"/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"* соответственно. Путь к make прописал в обоих случаях как *"/usr/bin/make"*. ABI настроен так: *x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit*.

Весь этот процесс был долгим (данный набор постоянно был с какими-нибудь ошибками и либо вовсе не появлялся среди наборов при создании проектов, либо не начинал компиляцию). В результате, я скомпилировал проект, но на целевой системе он не запустился (exec format error).

Библиотеку (curl) я собирал посредством cmake, и вроде вызывал ./configure --target=armhf-linux --with-libssh2 (это было порядка месяца назад, после решил взять перерыв), но что-то я, видимо, сделал по-прежнему не так.

Я был бы крайне признателен, если бы мне пошагово объяснили необходимую последовательность действий. Я более чем уверен, что здесь даже IDE не требуется. Просто я не знаю, как решить задачу без нее (ну, т.е. я знаю, пишешь makefile, запускаешь make и вуаля - компилируй хоть на целевой системе, но не думаю, что я напишу makefile).

Comment: `arm x86` - x86 это Intel а arm это ARM Holdings. arm x86 не существует. Cortex A7 это 32bit arm, надо компилировать под него.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, поправил сообщение.

Comment: по поводу опций для компилятора при сборке библиотеки: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Comment: а проще, вероятно, взять готовую сборку: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&arch=armhf&searchon=names&keywords=curl

Comment: О, благодарю, но разве это не установочные deb-пакеты? Мне же нужна статическая .a библиотека.

Comment: @АндрейСолодовников ознакомьтесь с [этим](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application)

Comment: *Мне же нужна статическая .a библиотека* — в пакетах, имена которых заканчиваются на `-dev`, есть и `lib*.a`, и `lib*.la`. [например](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/libcurl4-gnutls-dev/filelist). *разве это не установочные deb-пакеты?* — в первую очередь это файлы. внутри которых архивы с файлами. которые можно просто распаковать и использовать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за пояснение.